# Get Ebay product category from its URL with Python

Tags: python, ebay-api

I need to retrieve the customers intention-to-buy analyzing a large set of ebay urls. Since these urls are not semantically significant (i.e. I cannot parse the URL in order to find a useful information about the product), I was thinking to retrieve the 'product category' from its ebay URL. For product category I mean, for example,

- `Home & Garden>Bedding>Sheets & Pillowcases` or
- `Musical Instruments & Gear>Guitars & Basses`

I'm trying the`ebaysdk`(https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python) for Python, but I haven't find anything regarding the possibility of getting a category product from its URL.

Also with a different ebay api, is this feaseable?

Comment: May be it helps https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=category

Comment: i don't know how that helps me